# Can Haskell type synonyms be used as type constructors?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-constructor, type-synonyms

I'm writing a benchmark to compare the performance of a number of Haskell collections, including `STArray`, on a given task. To eliminate repetition, I'm trying to write a set of functions that provide a uniform interface to these collections, so that I can implement the task as a polymorphic higher-order function. More specifically, the task is implemented in terms of a polymorphic monad, which is `ST s` for `STArray`, and `Identity` for collections like `HashMap`, that do not typically need to be manipulated within a monad.

Due to uniformity requirements, I can't use the `Identity` and `HashMap` types directly, as I need their kinds to match the kinds of `ST` and `STArray`. I thought that the simplest way to achieve this would be to define type synonyms with phantom parameters:

```
type Identity' s a = Identity a
type HashMap' s i e = HashMap i e
-- etc.
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because when I try to use these synonyms as type constructors in places where I use `ST` and `STArray` as type constructors, GHC gives errors like:

```
The type synonym ‘Identity'’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
```

I came across the `-XLiberalTypeSynonyms` GHC extension, and thought it would allow me to do this, as the [documentation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/liberal_type_synonyms.html) says:

> You can apply a type synonym to a partially applied type synonym

and gives this example of doing so:

```
type Generic i o = forall x. i x -> o x
type Id x = x

foo :: Generic Id []
```

That example works in GHC 8.0.2 (with `-XExistentialQuantification` and `-XRank2Types`). But replacing `Generic` with a `newtype` or `data` declaration, as needed in my use case, does not work.
I.e. the following code leads to the same kind of error that I reported above:

```
newtype Generic i o = Generic (forall x. i x -> o x)
type Id x = x
foo :: Generic Id []
foo = Generic (\x -> [x])
```

## Question

Is there some other extension that I need to enable to get this to work? If not, is there a good reason why this doesn't work, or is it just an oversight?

## Workaround

I'm aware that I can work around this by defining `Identity'`, etc. as fully-fledged types, e.g.:

```
newtype Identity' s a = Identity' a
newtype Collection collection s i e = Collection (collection i e)
-- etc.
```

This is not ideal though, as it means that I have to reimplement `Identity`'s `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances for `Identity'`, and it means that I have to write additional wrapping and unwrapping code for the collections.

Comment: There's an open GHC proposal for first-class type families, but for now they (and type synonyms) are quite thoroughly second-class.

Comment: Ah ok, so the workaround is the easiest solution for now?

Comment: Yep! And I would bet it'll remain the best behaved way indefinitely.

Comment: Interesting - it sounds like there is some fundamental issue with type synonyms that I haven't yet appreciated, as an inexperienced user of the language. Do you know of any articles that will give someone like me, who knows very little about how GHC works, some sense of what the issue is?

Comment: There's really very little to say about type synonyms. They're particularly useful in combination with certain advanced type system extensions (`TypeFamilies`, `ConstraintKinds`, and sometimes `RankNTypes`). They occasionally show up elsewhere. They're rarely useful for beginners, and tend to confuse beginners more than they help.

Comment: The obvious solution to doing type inference in the presence of partially-applied type synonyms is higher-order unification. Unfortunately higher-order unification is undecidable. So the language eschews partial application of type synonyms in favor of simplicity.

Comment: A main issue is that, during type inference/type checking, GHC assumes that a type equality like `F a b ~ F a' b'` implies `a ~ a'` and `b ~ b'`, i.e. that type constructors are injective. This is exploited by the unification algorithm. Your `Identity'` synonym is not injective, instead (type families has the same issue), so -roughly- they have to be fully expanded and replaced by actual constructors before the rest of type checking. Hence they must be fully applied where this is needed, so that replacement can take place.